# Why does my PHP not activate when I embed it with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I embedded a PHP file with JavaScript but the PHP didn't work.
Here's what I did:

```
$.get("php/file.php");
```

In the **PHP** file:

```
<?php
    echo "Testing PHP File"
?>
```

I would really appreciate it if someone answered me!

Comment: what outcome are you expecting to happen?

Comment: that's not how client side v server side works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should used `$.get()` like this

```
$.get('php/file.php', function(data) {
                alert(data);//here is your "Testing PHP File" data
            });
```

**Make sure:** this will work on any event like `click` or other (i suppose you know about server side and client side)

```
$('.class_name').click(function() {
            $.get('php/file.php', function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                });
        });
```

Comment: in javascript used `console.log(data)` and if you want to see output then press F12 button and goto console tab and your output in console tab

Answer (score 3):

```
$.get("php/file.php");
```

works on client side and since you are not doing anything after the request, it will look like its not working.

Always consider reading the [Docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/).

There its explained very nicely. Copying the code from there as an example.

```
  var jqxhr = $.get( "example.php", function() {
    alert( "success" );
  })
  .done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a callback function to make this work. In this case, that can be the second paremeter

```
$.get('php/file.php', function(data) {
    // do someting with your data
});
```

[more on $.get](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest you to read the [jQuery Docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) or read some stuff, but for you the really helpful content on that page is examples section, in that first example is same as your question which is as below:

```
$.get( "test.php" );
```

**it will Request the test.php page(in your case php/file.php), but ignore the return results.**
If you want to alert the returned data then use function() in $.get() as below:

```
$.get( "test.php", function( data ) {
  alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});
```

You can also print it on html if you want , if you have any tag with `id="output"` in your html here i am taking it for example you can have any jquery selector(class,element etc) then you can print it as below:

```
$.get( "php/file.php", function( data ) {
  $('#output').html(data);
});
//output: Testing PHP File
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this to catch your data outside the `$.get callback`

```
var data_;
$.get('php/file.php', function(data
{ data_ = data});
alert(data_);
```

you can instead call the php file using `php include` instead of `jquery $.get`

```
<script>
<?php include 'php/file.php';?>
</script>
```

In the above example, whatever you echo inside the `<script>` tag must be a **valid** JavaScript syntax.